# PHP Header refresh with post variables

Tags: php

I have seen this script

```
<?php header("Location: secondpage.php", TRUE, 307); ?>
```

I have also seen this script

```
<?php header("refresh:2; url=secondpage.php"); ?>
```

I want something like the combination of both. I tried the script below, but didnt work. Is there a way this can be done?

```
<?php header("refresh:2; url=secondpage.php", TRUE, 307); ?>
```

I also tried the script below, but didnt work. Is there a way this can be done?

```
<?php header("refresh:2; url=secondpage.php", FALSE, 307); ?>
```

The point is to have the delay and still send the post on redirect.

eg.

FROM: firstpage.php

REDIRCT TO: secondpage.php (use $_POST from firstpage.php here)

REDIRCT AGAIN TO: thirdpage.php (use $_POST from firstpage.php here also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boolean Flag TRUE OR FALSE in the `header()` determines whether you want the current `header()` to replace a previous one. If you want multiple headers, set it to FALSE. By default, this is TRUE... This means any subsequent `header()` replaces the Previous One. The 3rd Parameter is the HTTP RESPONSE CODE.

To explicitly set the Response Code to 307, You can use PHP `http_response_code($code)`. Combining the 2, You can have something like this:

```
    // EXPLICITLY SET RESPONSE CODE TO 307
    http_response_code(307); 

    // REFRESH & REDIRECT TO page.php  
    // IN FACT; THERE IS NO NEED FOR THE http_response_code(307) ABOVE
    // THIS ONE LINE DOES IT ALL IN ONE GO... 
    header("refresh:2; url=page.php", FALSE, 307);
```

If you increased the `refresh` to (say) 15 so that you have enough time to look into the the Browser's `Web-Developer Tools` (under the `Networks Tab`), You'd notice that the HTTP Response Code of `307` was indeed set & sent....

To pass some data from the current page to `page.php`, You have 2 Options. Pass the Data via `$_GET` like so:

```
<?php
    $url    = urlencode("page.php?user=web&password=develop‌​per&city=bronx");
    header("refresh:2; url={$url}", FALSE, 307);
```

Or You could use Session like so:

```
<?php

    //FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT:
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }

    // SET SOME DATA INTO THE $_SESSION (TO BE USED IN page.php, ETC.)
    $_SESSION['user']   = 'web';
    $_SESSION['pass']   = 'develop‌​per';
    $_SESSION['city']   = 'bronx';

    header("refresh:2; url=page.php", FALSE, 307);
```

Comment: Ok. But i am still unable to receive my POST variables on page.php even after setting the flag to FALSE.

Comment: If you want to POST data to `page.php`, there are 2 ways: You can either Use Session or Pass them as query strings to the header like so:  `header("refresh:2; url=page.php?username=web&password=developer&city=new-york", FALSE, 307);`

Comment: Ok. useful addition to the answer but more importantly i am trying to get my POST variables from my very first page(firstpage.php) to my third page(thirdpage.php). I would rather not use sessions. Please see my edited question if this helps to explain my problem.

Comment: I tried header("refresh:2; url=page.php?usernam‌​e='".$_POST['postVarFromFirstPage']."'", FALSE, 307); But this didnt work too

Comment: @ken            ***You can't expressly eat your cake and still have it back;*** now, can you? *How did you plan to explicitly send http header & post some request simultaneously on a page which only was ON for 2 seconds...* In the end: you'd come to either accept the `$_GET` alternative or the `$_SESSION`

Comment: @ken            ***Where is the $_POST['postVa‌​rFromFirstPage'] coming from?*** Truth is: Only YOU can see what it is that you have over there. To assist, we may need to share the same Plate. Now, where is that value `$_POST['postVa‌​rFromFirstPage']` declared: Before the Header? After the Header?   Try this at the very top of your page: `var_dump($_POST['postVa‌​rFromFirstPage']); exit;`. What did you get?

Comment: i ended up making do with sessions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below header must be work

```
header("Refresh: 2; url=page.php");
```

If it is not working then make sure you have no echo statement after header.

Check this link:-

[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

**Using HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=page.php">
```